# Mathematica not creating Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Trying to make a graph according to the  [documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0obkq-hf93jr), but it isn't being made. I try plotting with no success; it seems like the graph isn't being created.

Does this have anything to do with importing Combinatorica?

[image: Error message]

Comment: I think so, yes. The fact that Graph is red indicates a name collision.

Comment: Most of the functionality of Combinatorica is built into Mathematica since version 10.

Comment: @DanielHuber The problem is that I need HamiltonianPath[] from Combinatoria which unfortunately is not in-built. Is there a way to use both functions at the same time?

Comment: Try: System`Graph[...] and Combinatorica`Graph[...]

Comment: @Trun Vishal why not FindHamiltonianPath?

Comment: @halmir Pardon me for being unspecific. I want to list out all the hamiltonian paths with HamiltonianPath[g, All]

Comment: @DanielHuber It seems like graphs made with System`Graph[] do not work with Combinatoria's functions. Combinatoria`Graph[] does not seem to make graphs.

Comment: You are right. I tried: `?? Combinatorica`Graph` and the syntax seems rather different from `?? System`Graph`  . However, I could not figure the syntax of  `?? Combinatorica`Graph` .

Comment: @TrunVishal The IGraph/M package replaces almost all of the graph-related functionality of the old Combinatorica package, and will perform much better. You can use subisomorphism functions for this task: `IGVF2FindSubisomorphisms[PathGraph@Range@VertexCount[g], g]` gets all Hamiltonian paths in the Petersen graph. Note that each path is returned twice, once in each direction.